# "Smart" method to solve a subset sum problem with multiple sets

Tags: python, subset-sum

I have a certain amount of sets, each containing a variable amount of unique numbers - unique in the set they belong to and that can't be found in others.

I'd like to make an algorithm implemented preferably in Python - but it can be any other language - that find one combination of number from each of these sets that sums to a specified number, knowing, if this helps, that there can be the same set multiple times, and an element from a set can be reused.

Practical example: let's say I have the following sets:

```
A = {1, 3, 6, 7, 15}
B = {2, 8, 10}
C = {4, 5, 9, 11, 12}
```

I want to obtain a number combination with a method `find_subset_combination(expected_sum, subset_list)`

```
>>> find_subset_combination(41, [A, B, B, C, B])
[1, 8, 10, 12, 10]
```

A solution to this problem has already been proposed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28099407/11736696), however it is rather a brute-force approach; as the number of sets and their size will be much larger in my case, I'd like an algorithm functioning with **the least number of iteration** possible.

What approach would you suggest me ?

Comment: Can the elements per set be re-used?

Comment: @wim Yes it can. I will update the question to clarify

Comment: The example suggest you only need to find one combination, not the total count of solutions nor an enumeration of the solves. Is that correct?

Comment: This is NP-hard. You're not going to find an efficient, general solution.

Comment: @wim This is correct. As finding one combination can already be quite difficult, I am not asking for multiple solutions. I already have an idea on how to find other possible combinations from one.

Comment: This sounds like a variations of "counting change" or "knapsack" problems. The difference being that the set of possible choices is different at each iteration.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly lets solve this for just two sets. This is known as the 'two sum' problem. You have two sets `a` and `b` that add to `l`. Since `a + b = l` we know that `l - a = b`. This is important as we can determine if `l - a` is in `b` in O(1) time. Rather than looping through `b` to find it in O(b) time. This means we can solve the 2 sum problem in O(a) time.

**Note**: For brevity the provided code only produces one solution. However changing `two_sum` to a generator function can return them all.

```py
def two_sum(l, a, b):
    for i in a:
        if l - i in b:
            return i, l - i
    raise ValueError('No solution found')
```

Next we can solve the 'four sum' problem. This time we have four sets `c`, `d`, `e` and `f`. By combining `c` and `d` into `a`, and `e` and `f` into `b` we can use `two_sum` to solve the problem in O(cd + ef) space and time. To combine the sets we can just use a cartesian product, adding the results together.

**Note**: To get all results perform a cartesian product on all resulting `a[i]` and `b[j]`.

```py
import itertools


def combine(*sets):
    result = {}
    for keys in itertools.product(*sets):
        results.setdefault(sum(keys), []).append(keys)
    return results


def four_sum(l, c, d, e, f):
    a = combine(c, d)
    b = combine(e, f)
    i, j = two_sum(l, a, b)
    return (*a[i][0], *b[j][0])
```

It should be apparent that the 'three sum' problem is just a simplified version of the 'four sum' problem. The difference is that we're given `a` at the start rather than being asked to calculate it. This runs in O(a + ef) time and O(ef) space.

```py
def three_sum(l, a, e, f):
    b = combine(e, f)
    i, j = two_sum(l, a, b)
    return (i, *b[j][0])
```

Now we have enough information to solve the 'six sum' problem. The question comes down to how do we divide all these sets?

- If we decide to pair them together then we can use the 'three sum' solution to get what we want. *But* this may not run in the best time, as it runs in O(ab + bcde), or O(n^4) time if they're all the same size.
- If we decide to put them in trios then we can use the 'two sum' to get what we want. This runs in O(abc + def), or O(n^3) if they're all the same size.

At this point we should have all the information to make a generic version that runs in O(n^⌈s/2⌉) time and space. Where s is the amount of sets entered into the function.

```py
def n_sum(l, *sets):
    midpoint = len(sets) // 2
    a = combine(*sets[:midpoint])
    b = combine(*sets[midpoint:])
    i, j = two_sum(l, a, b)
    return (*a[i][0], *b[j][0])
```

You can further optimize the code. The size of both sides of the two sum matter quite a lot.

- To exemplify this you can imagine 4 sets of 1 number on one side and 4 sets of 1000 numbers on the other. This will run in O(1^4 + 1000^4) time. Which is obviously *really* bad. Instead you can balance both sides of the two sum to make it much smaller. By having 2 sets of 1 number and 2 sets of 1000 numbers on both sides of the equation the performance increases; O(1^2×1000^2 + 1^2×1000^2) or simply O(1000^2). Which is far smaller than O(1000^4).
- Expanding on the previous point if you have 3 sets of 1000 numbers and 3 sets of 10 numbers then the best solution is to put two 1000s on one side and everything else on the other side:

  - 1000^2 + 10^3×1000 = 2_000_000
  - Interlaced sorted and same size either side (10, 1000, 10), (1000, 10, 1000)
    10^2×1000 + 10×1000^2 = 10_100_000

Additionally if there is an even amount of each set provided then you can cut the time it takes to run in half by only calling `combine` once. For example if the input is `n_sum(l, a, b, c, a, b, c)` (without the above optimizations) it should be apparent that the second call to `combine` is only a waste of time and space.

Comment: Very interesting idea, even if I'll need more time to fully understand and assimilate all these explanations. Just a sad note, the algorithmic solution revealed upon a test with a quite large amount of sets (20 with the capacity of each ranging from 5 to 80) to be extremily memory intensive.